# Getting error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure defined in SQL Server as below and when I try to execute it with

```
EXEC SP_PUBLISH_D1 114, '2021-01-05', 'test123', '2021-01-06';
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Stored procedure code:

```
@Version INT,
@UpdatedOn date ,
@Updateby  nvarchar(MAX),
@EffectiveDate date
```

Comment: You might try changing those date literals to '20210105' and '20210106'. You didn't share the SP code where the problem might really be.

Comment: Unless your server language is not English, the error will be inside the sproc, which you have not posted

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: in your stored procedure probably you used the wrong parameter. for example; AnyDateField = @UpdatedBy